# Mysql : Count(*) query issue after upgrading mysql 8.0.34 from mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table `holidays` with id, lable, start_date, end_date columns with timestamps.
datatypes are bigint, varchar, date, date.

when i ran `select count(*) from holidays`, aws rds cpu utilization to high. this query is frequently running my app. so cpu utilization went 100%. This happens only after mysql upgrade to 8.0.34.

Previously it was in mysql 5.7, i didnt face this issue. went through all forums and docs didnt get the exact fix.

Anything need to be updated in aws parameter group? or any config level changes?

- Source code: Laravel 8.0
- Database: mysql 8.0

Aws RDS is used.

Comment: Did you switch from MyISAM to InnoDB when you upgraded? InnoDB doesn't cache table sizes, so the query is slower.

Comment: Also if not what @Barmar mentioned, try running [analyze table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) on your table(s)

Comment: Also you may try to use not `COUNT(*)` but `COUNT(table.id)` where `id` is non-NULL indexed column.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE holidays; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "holidays"; for analysis.